# Convert a array having bits into one byte

Tags: java

I m trying to convert 8 bits into one byte. The way the bits are represented are by using a byte object that only contains a 1 or a 0.

If i have a 8 length byte array with these bits, how can i convert them into one byte.

```
public byte bitsToByte(byte[] bits) {
 //Something in here. Each byte inside bits is either a 1 or a 0.
}
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Why not add the powers of two where there's a 1? It's just binary.

Comment: You want to convert byte to bits?

Comment: your each bit in itself a `byte` type,  don't get confused between Java data types and pure meaning of bits and bytes. Do you mean concatenating those bits to get a single byte format?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`left shift` by 1 first for each `bit` in the array and then add the bit to the `byte`.

The implementation is based on the assumption that `first` bit in the array is sign bit and following bits are the magnitude in higher to lower positions of the byte.

```
public byte bitsToByte(byte[] bits) {
  byte value = 0;
  for (byte b : bits) {
    value <<=1;
    value += b;
  }
  return value;
}
```

Test the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  BitsToByte bitsToByte = new BitsToByte();
  byte bits[] = new byte[]{0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1};  // 1 + 0 + 4 + 8 + 0 + 32 + 0 + 0
  byte value = bitsToByte.bitsToByte(bits);
  System.out.println(value);
}
```

output:

```
45
```

---

Covert the `byte` array into a `byte` value (in the same order):

```
public static byte bitsToByte1(byte[] bits){
  byte result = 0;
  for (byte i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
    byte tmp = bits[i];
    tmp <<= i;             // Perform the left shift by "i" times. "i" position of the bit
    result |= tmp;         // perform the bit-wise OR 
  }
  return result;
}
```

input: (same array in reverse)

```
  byte bits1[] = new byte[]{1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0};
  value = bitsToByte1(bits1);
  System.out.println(value);
```

output:

```
45
```

Comment: Left shifting by one is just a multiplication by two; how will that add 4 and 8 to the byte? Wouldnt you left shift by several places to build the correct number?

Comment: If you are referencing `4` (third position from right) and `8` (forth position from right) from the above example then that is value represented by a bit in the byte. Yes. we will be doing the left shift each time we get a bit. I guess that what I am doing. I hope I got you correctly.

Comment: Downvotes are good way provide feedback but adding some words to it will make it a best way. IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static byte bitsToByte(byte[] bits){
    byte b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        b |= (bits[i]&1) << i;
    return b;
}

//as an added bonus, the reverse.
public static byte[] bitsToByte(byte bits){
    byte[] b = new byte[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        b[i] = (byte) ((bits&(1 << i)) >>> i);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Downvotes are good way to provide feedback but adding some words to it will make it a best way. IMHO